# WPF tab control access previous tab data

Tags: wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I am using WPF Tab control with MVVM model.
i have two 2 tabs say Tab1 and Tab2.
In tab1 i have some data like first name which is filled in tabl now if i got tab2 i need to access the tab1 value.

how to do this
thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are using MVVM model you may share a model class with the data between those tabs.

Answer (score 0):

provided both tabs are under the same Datacontext, both tabs should have access to the viewmodel properties that "tab 1" binds to.

also, ["ElementName" bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) will work accross tabs.

Comment: Each tab is loading different view models.

Comment: Element name bindings will still work across view models.. Another option is to introduce some ViewModel communication to sync values between the two... simply add a ref to the other VM or to a singleton class in both VMs (shared data) or allot of people like messaging systems like that in the MVVM-Light toolkit or PRISM, IIRC you can use either of these stand-alone (i.e. you don't need to use the rest of the toolkit)